# Snowflake Procedure Migration

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can some one help me in guiding is this is the best way of converting an oracle procedure to snowflake via JS.

Oracle Proc:

PROCEDURE ABC (LOGGED_USER       IN VARCHAR,
request_date      IN VARCHAR,
page              IN VARCHAR,
activity          IN VARCHAR,
payload_request   IN VARCHAR,
CHANGED_USER      IN VARCHAR)
IS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO ABCD (LOGGED_USER,
request_date,
page,
activity,
payload_request,
CHANGED_USER)
VALUES (LOGGED_USER,
TO_DATE (request_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
page,
activity,
payload_request,
CHANGED_USER);
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS
THEN
INSERT INTO ABCD (LOGGED_USER,
request_date,
page,
activity,
payload_request,
CHANGED_USER)
VALUES (LOGGED_USER,
'',
page,
activity,
payload_request,
CHANGED_USER);
END ABC;

Snowflake Proc

create or replace procedure xxxxx ( LOGGED_USER STRING, REQUEST_DATE STRING, PAGE STRING, ACTIVITY STRING, PAYLOAD_REQUEST STRING, CHANGED_USER STRING ) language javascript as $ $ try { var query = "INSERT INTO ABC (LOGGED_USER, REQUEST_DATE, PAGE, ACTIVITY, PAYLOAD_REQUEST, CHANGED_USER) VALUES ({$LOGGED_USER}, TO_DATE ({$REQUEST_DATE}, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), {$PAGE}, {$ACTIVITY}, {$PAYLOAD_REQUEST}, {$CHANGED_USER});" var sql = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: query }); var result = sql.execute(); } catch(error) { var query = "INSERT INTO ABC (LOGGED_USER, REQUEST_DATE, PAGE, ACTIVITY, PAYLOAD_REQUEST, CHANGED_USER) VALUES ({$LOGGED_USER}, 'NULL', {$PAGE}, {$ACTIVITY}, {$PAYLOAD_REQUEST}, {$CHANGED_USER});" var sql = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: query }); var result = sql.execute(); return error.message; } $$;

Thanks ,
Nikhil

Comment: Hi, assuming your Snowflake SP works, I’m not sure what you are asking. What’s your definition of “best way”?

Comment: Hi Nick, I just need a guidance is this the right way of converting oracle procedure into snowflake.

Comment: Not many people know about migrating a procedure, but instead you could tell us what's the goal of the new procedure, what have you tried so far, and what error messages you see.

Comment: i am planning to move one of the oracle procedure to snwoflake, as a POC work